# What does "except with" mean?

Tags: prepositions

I am wondering if you use the following phrase? Or, is it archaic? and is there any difference between **except for** and **except with**?

except with

Thanks

Comment: This question would be answerable, except for the fact that you gave no examples. So I cannot answer your question, except with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Except for" is an established phrase which means "with the exception of": http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/except%20for

"Except with" is not a correct English phrase as far as I was able to verify.

Answer (score 1):

"Except for" is more common, but "except with" is certainly used.[image] 
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=except+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexcept%20with%3B%2Cc0

"Except with" is used to specify the conditions of an exception to a rule or condition, as in

> "Except with proper authorization, parking on protected property is
>   not allowed without a permit."
>
> "Youths of all races unable to respond to affection except with
>   suspicion, unable to handle any problem except with rage, children
>   disturbed by an endless list of family and social ills."

"Except for" also deals with exceptions, although it is generally used to identify the exception.

> "Everyone had arrived except for the guest of honor."